# What is the easiest way to write dimensional expression?

Tags: calculations

I want to do the following arithmetic:

`(x-y)*unit/s` where `x`, `y`, `s` are rational constants and `unit` is in length unit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\unit
\unit=16pt
\def\x{0.5}
\def\y{0.3}
\def\s{0.8}

\newlength\temp
\begin{document}
\temp=\unit/\real{\s}*(\real{\x}-\real{\y})\relax
\the\temp
\end{document}
```

What is the easiest way to write dimensional expression?

Comment: you want the code to do the calculation?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I want to pass in the final value to `includegraphics`' `viewport`.

Comment: I don't think that `calc` is able to do sums with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest the easiest way is to calculate it using PGF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newlength\unit
\unit=16pt
\def\x{0.5}
\def\y{0.3}
\def\s{0.8}
\newlength\temp
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetlength{\temp}{\unit/\s*(\x-\y)}
\the\temp
\includegraphics[width=\temp]{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you pass it to `\includegraphics`, always better as a macro parameter.

```
 \def\putgraphic#1{%
   \includegraphics[viewport=#1 10 20 20]{test.png}}
 \putgraphic{\temp}
```

Comment: Please wait, I will pass in the final value to `viewport`. I hope there is no problem.

Comment: @Guaranteed for seven years:)

Comment: @Forgiver Just remember to enclose `\temp` or `\unit` in braces: `viewport=0 0 {\temp} {\temp}`

Comment: @egreg: Can I use `\space` instead of `{}`?

Comment: @Forgiver I don't think so.

Comment: @Forgiver If you pass as a parameter is ok with spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Here's with `expl3` and the `fp` module (not the expandable version):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l_forgiver_factor_fp
\NewDocumentCommand{\xys}{ O{\funit} m m m }
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l_forgiver_factor_fp { #2 }
  \fp_sub:Nn \l_forgiver_factor_fp { #3 }
  \fp_div:Nn \l_forgiver_factor_fp { #4 }
  #1 = \fp_use:N \l_forgiver_factor_fp #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newlength\funit
\setlength\funit{16pt}

\begin{document}   
\xys{3.125}{2.175}{2.5}\the\funit
\end{document}
```

This will output

> 6.08008pt

that complies from `echo "16*(3.125-2.175)/2.5" | bc -l`, which actually prints

> 6.08000000000000000000

You can set other lengths by calling

```
\xyz[\mylen]{<x>}{<y>}{<s>}
```